# Fwrite are not writing data in a file. C programming language

Tags: c, fwrite, error-code

I have a binary file previously wrote with some struct but when i try to enter some data into the file with the function **write_disc_eof** the function fwrite don't write the data on the file.

If i change fopen mode to wb or wb+ fwrite do succefully write the data on the file but i want to append and neither "rb+","ab" or "ab+" on fopen let fwrite insert the data. The **fwrite** return succefully in any case but the data don't appear still. I tried to use **fflush** but nothing too. Could anyone help me?

Notes - 
/* This functions perfectly in any file of the code*/
** search_fdisc_code(FILE_LOCATION,CODE) ** : search if the file has some register with the same code.
** load_fdisc(FILE_LOCATION,MODEtoFOPEN) ** : fopen + error handle.

I have the following code:

/* The Flawed Function that tries to write at EOF*/

```
int write_disc_eof(const char* destino, disciplina **disc){
    FILE *fp;
    int ctrl;
    node_disc *temp;     
    disciplina *d;

    d=*disc;

    ctrl = search_fdisc_code(destino,d->cod_disciplina);
    if(ctrl){
        printf("Código de Disciplina já existe! Não pode inserir!");
        return 0;          
    }

    fp = load_fdisc(destino,"rb+");    
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);   
    ctrl = fwrite(&(d->id_disciplina),sizeof(unsigned int),1,fp);
    ctrl = fwrite(&(d->creditos),sizeof(unsigned int),1,fp);
    ctrl = fwrite(&(d->carga_horaria),sizeof(unsigned int),1,fp);
    ctrl = fwrite(&(d->num_requisitos),sizeof(unsigned int),1,fp);
    ctrl = fwrite(d->cod_disciplina,sizeof(char),10,fp);
    ctrl = fwrite(d->nome,sizeof(char),50,fp);

    ctrl = d->num_requisitos;
    if(!ctrl){      
        fclose(fp);
        return 2;   
    }

    for(temp=(d->pre_requisitos)->head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->proximo)
    {        
        fwrite(temp->proximo,sizeof(char),10,fp);
    }   
    fclose(fp); 
    return 1;                          
}
```

Comment: just a side note, you do realize you can instantly write a structure? If you're writing all fields anyway you might as well write it in one go

Comment: *The fwrite return succefully in any case*. You never test if `fwrite` worked properly...

Comment: Thanks for the tip Jean.
1 - yes, i could use fwrite(&STRUCT,sizeof(STRUCT),1,PT) to do that, i know but good point.
2 - i try to understand why fwrite is not writing inside the file so i tried to test the return to eliminate the possibility (even small) of some write error due to it.

Comment: you need to check fwrite return value after each write. In your case you would check to see if ctrl == (size * nmemb). See manpage of fwrite for details on what is returned.

Comment: i checked all of then but they return with success. I can't write through this function and that is what bothering me.